# what ist the equivalent to Edittext.Setinputtype in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

In my Xamarin Android app I want to change the InputType of a Edititext in code.

But the Xamarin EditText has no setInputType method.

I tried:

```
  public void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;

        sf = spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
        if (sf == "kdnr" || sf == "plz")    // those field are numeric
        { _suchkun.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber; }
        else
        { _suchkun.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText; }

    }
```

---

but without succes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made an answer [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/6914/#Comment_6914), which demonstrates switching `InputType` on the fly while typing.

Basically you are doing it correct, you simply assign a value to the `InputType` property, which is the equivalent of using `setInputType` in Java Android.

```
_suchkun.InputType = InputTypes.ClassNumber;
```

That is all you should need to do.

Comment: But my app crashes as soon as the edittext gets focus, no matter if I use InputTypes.ClassNumber or InputTypes.ClassText

Comment: Then you have an entirely different problem, which I only can guess what is without seeing a stack trace and the exact code which triggers it.